# Replace Log4j with Logback in Kafka Connect

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, logback

I am currently using [confluentinc/cp-server-connect](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-server-connect/tags) as ase Docker image for my Kafka Connect Worker nodes. I want to substitute Log4j 1.x with Logback. Reason - [KIP-653](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-653%3A+Upgrade+log4j+to+log4j2) not available yet and also I am hoping to use `logstash-logback-encoder` for formatting log messages.

**Problem** : How to do it ? What changes in mentioned base image should be required if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka uses reload4j now, rather than log4j 1.x explicitly. There are classes and configuration scripts that have that hard coded, so simply replacing logging libraries isn't as simple as swapping jars out.

In the image that I maintain, I use log4j2 https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker

> hoping to use logstash-logback-encoder for formatting log messages.

Reload4j PatternLayout can format messages too

Comment: This seems like good solution. Any idea how can I achieve something similar while using `confluentinc/cp-server-connect`  as my base image

Comment: "Logstash can parse regular Kafka Connect....." - I am not using Logstash. that library has no dependency on logstash as such, it simply generates logs in json format.. which can be used with / without logstash in picture. in my case logs gets ingested to Azure log analytics..

Comment: Log4j2 also has json encoder pattern. The Confluent images are preloaded with reload4j, and cannot easily be modified to use logback without breaking internal components and scripts. That's why I built my own and recompiled without other logging libraries... Azure log analytics should be able to understand Java stacktraces and logs, too